# Javascript - AJAX displaying image from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I've already getting the file name of the image in my table using json which my code is `$("show_product_img").val(data.picture);`, now I want to show the image in my page. In my var `urlimg` is the link where my images are stored. So I will call the `urlimg` and get the file name of my image which is in `$("show_product_img").val(data.picture);`

How will I show the image in my page? BTW I'm using codeigniter framework, here's my code.

**AJAX**

```
var prodid = $("#prod-names option:selected").attr("value");
var url = "http://localhost:800/client_ayos/administrator/createpromoajax/"+prodid;
var urlimg = "http://localhost:800/client_ayos/uploads/"; //this is where the images are stored
var type = "GET";

$.getJSON( url,type, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#orig-price").val(data.price);
    $("#supplier").val(data.supplier); 
    $("show_product_img").val(data.picture);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="product_img" hidden>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Product Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img  id="show_product_img" class="form-control" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group" id="product_img" hidden>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Product Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img  id="show_product_img" class="form-control" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Change JS ..

```
var image = document.getElementById("show_product_img");
image.src = data.picture;
```

use this to set the image.

or simply..

```
document.getElementById("show_product_img").src = data.picture;
```

Using jQuery

```
$("#show_product_img").attr("src",data.picture);
```

Comment: i tried your codes still doesnt work. i have storage of all images in my database i put it in ../uploads/ which in my code is var urlimg = "http://localhost:800/client_ayos/uploads/"; maybe that's why it didnt show, i would like to ask how can i call that url so it can show the image

Comment: the file name of the image of my product like image.jpg  so to show the image i think the  var urlimg = "localhost:800/client_ayos/uploads/" which the link where all the images(with their specfic file names and file extension) are stored. so how can i do with ajax the urlimg + the data.picture

Comment: open console on chrome 'ctrl+shift+j' and go to network tab.. and reload the page .. You will see the url of the image in red.. check the url .. if its pointing to the correct location or not.. and change it accordingly..

Comment: i've already solved it with this $("#show_product_img").attr("src",imgurl + data.picture); thanks a lot for your help